# Showing form when main form gets closed

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have tried around with threads a little bit but I can't figure out the right way to get what I want (because I'm not very familiar with threads).
I have a "Sign out" button in my main form. When clicked then the Form shuts completely down and restarts (Application.Restart()). Now I wanted another form pop up when the main form gets closed (Just a label with "Loging out - Please wait"). When the main form opens then this "Log out form" should disappear. 
I know I should make the Sign out form as foreground thread but how do I call the Form.Open() method with the thread and how I can get it closed when the main form starts?

Comment: Just create the form; it'll get torn down and go away on its own when `Application.Restart` finishes running.

Comment: How to do that exactly? It doesn't seem to work. I think I do something wrong.

Comment: You create a form and show it...that should be sufficient.

Comment: I tried that before the Application.Restart() method and after that (without using a thread). Doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't descriptive at all.  What is the problem?

Comment: Nothing happens. The main form shuts down and restarts. The other form doesn't show up at any moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to show the second form in the FormClosing event of the main form.

When the main form closes it most certainly "shuts down" the message loop of the application making it impossible to spawn any new window or closing any window that is already open.

Edit:
As of the comments: Showing the logout form from the process that is about to Restart until the new process has been started successfully will not be possible because the old process will be shut down and therefore any open form it shows.

Possible solutions:

- Write a program with the solely purpose of showing the logout form and start that before restarting the application. After the Application has startet again search the process of the logout form and stop/kill it.
- Avoid to have to restart your application completely

Comment: Does not work. It crashes at the Application.Restart(). Isn't it possible somehow to run a new thread when closing the main form and kill it when the main form loads?

Comment: As far as i understand you want to show a "logging out" form while the main form closes and the application restarts and hide it when the new process of your app has finished loading. Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly! Maybe hiding wouldn't be the best because of performance issues. Killing the thread would be better I think or at least interrupt it.

Comment: The problem with Application.Restart is, that it shuts down your current process and then starts a new process. Therefore i think you can not show a "logging out" form this way because it gets killed before the new process is launched. You can maybe write a small exe which shows that logout form. Start it when your main form is closing and search for that process when your main form opens again and kill it. OR avoid to have to restart your application completely

Comment: Ok thank you! Is it then possible to show the logOut form correctly before shutting down the main form? I tried  (logOut.Show()) to write it before the restart command with a Thread.Sleep. He shows the form a couple seconds before the main form closes but the text labels are somehow corrupted (one can't see the text - just the form of the labels).

Comment: I guess the sleeping is preventing the opened form to paint its content completely. Try to put your sleep into a loop and call [Application.DoEvents()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) in the loop. For example: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(100); Application.DoEvents(); }`